# How to access Zustand store outside a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, zustand

So I have a util.ts file where I am declaring a function which can be used in multiple place. For that I am accessing a variable and function from Zustand store.

```
import useStore from "@/store/useStore";

const { roomState, setRoomState } = useStore()

const utililtyFunctions = {
    sha512: (str: string) => {
        return crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", new TextEncoder().encode(str)).then(buf => {
            return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buf), x => (('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2))).join('');
        });
    },

    addRoom: (roomState: {
        room_no: number;
        adult: number;
        child: number;
        infant: number;
    }[], min_inv: number) => {
        if (roomState.length < min_inv) {
            setRoomState([
                ...roomState,
                {
                    room_no: roomState.length + 1,
                    adult: 0,
                    child: 0,
                    infant: 0,
                },
            ]);
        }
    },
}

export default utililtyFunctions;
```

But I am getting the following error:

`React Hook "useStore" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Please let me know how can I resolve this. Or let me know any better solution to achieve the same functionalities.

Comment: You can use hook outside the react component. You can still use `setRoomState` outside the component like this: `useStore.getState().setRoomState(...)`. More for info, you can follow the [Zustand Docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#readingwriting-state-and-reacting-to-changes-outside-of-components).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version fo example [taken from the doc](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#readingwriting-state-and-reacting-to-changes-outside-of-components):

```js
import { create } from 'zustand'

const useStore = create(() => ({ paw: true, snout: true, fur: true }))

// Getting non-reactive fresh state
const paw = useStore.getState().paw

useStore.setState({ paw: false })
useStore.setState({ snout: false })

// You can of course use the hook as you always would
function Component() {
  const paw = useStore((state) => state.paw)
  // ...
}
```

So in your case the right way to update room state is `useStore.setState(newState)` OR `useStore.getState().setRoomState()`

Comment: Doc link is down sadly

Comment: @JulienG unfortunately this part of the doc has been deleted, I updated the link with a github section describing the behavior, that's the only place I could find that info.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactflow.dev/learn/advanced-use/state-management
use this to manage the state in the Zustand library (use shallow is must).
In the custom node, we get the initial data. And whenever you change something in the node. Supply that change to the Zustand library using a function inside it.
eg:

```
updateNode: (data) => {
      if (!data) {
        return;
      }
      set((state) => {
        const node = state.nodes[1];
        node.data = data;
      });
    }
```

This is never re-render all the nodes. And still get the updates to node data by node. Now save the updated changes in the zustand state to the server.