react-pluggable library - how to pass props to component rendered using getRendererComponent and renderer
Im exploring solutions for being able to wire in custom features into a a generic React application and am looking at the react-pluggable library to do this. Creating pluggable functions and passing args to them is fine, but if I want to render some pluggable UI and pass props to it then there doesn't seem to be a way o0r at least there's no examples of doing so in their docs, which feels very limiting.
In Code I have a CustomUIPlugin component with the following code
activate(): void {
  this.pluginStore.executeFunction("Renderer.add", "custom-button", () => (
    <Button>A Custom Button</Button>
  ));
}

Which I then render in another component via:
const pluginStore: any = usePluginStore();
let Renderer = pluginStore.executeFunction("Renderer.getRendererComponent");

return (
  <>
    <Renderer placement={"custom-button"} />
  </>
);

What I want to be able to do is pass a property to the component being rendered via the plugin. Is there any way to do this? I had hoped I could just do
activate(): void {
  this.pluginStore.executeFunction("Renderer.add", "custom-button", (label: string) => 
  (
    <Button>{label}</Button>
  ));
}  

But the value of label is always an empty object and so the rendering errors

It's probably best not to rely on a 4 year old dead project! Just my two pence, but as an experienced React dev who has worked on enterprise-scale projects, I think the overall pattern it purports to support is a false abstraction. You can do "feature based" with just...react. But maybe I just didnt get it. Do you have a more complete use case about what you want to achieve? In other words what type of "customer features" do you imagine?

Using the custom button example the most idiomatic way of solving your problem would be to simply wrap the whole app in a Context that allows things like a custom  Button component to be passed in. Then use that by pulling the relevant context where you need a button. You could also use somehing like Zustand  instead which are modern react stores that also already have a mechanism to manipulate them from the "outside" of react. In a similar vane, youd store the custom component in a store and use that where needed.

Zustand example https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113703/1086398

Actually the more I look at react-pluggable the more I understand it is actually just a overly idiosyncratic "store" library that never took off, but happened to have "plugin" in the name. The modern solutions these days would be zustand, jotai, valtio etc. The are generic stores with react bindings which also have the capability to be interacted with from the outside. And they dont have the weird api of react-pluggable. If you want, you can store functions, components, anything. And access them anywhere in react tree.

We created and used a version of react-pluggable with BuilderX.io. The library isn't maintained anymore. It's a pretty small library. Please take inspirations, fork it and build your own plugin system on top of it.

@adsy My use case is that much of the UI will be rendered dynamically based on config in data. 95% of the components will be generic and live in the base project. But I need to be able to include custom components that dont live in the base project.  I was exploring ways of doing this and have since started looking at dynamic imports and importing components from an external component library at build time based on configuration, so I know my deployed build will include any custom components that are then referenced in and dynamically loaded from config in data.

Yep that could work if you know the possibilities ahead of time (sounds like you do). It will probably be a bit annoying though to manage the runtime "switch" where the import statements are (in lower level files for deep components). Things will probably get easier if you  do the dynamic import in bulk in a common ancestor and use some store like i mentioned so you can colocate all that dynamic fetching logic into one central place. Lower level /deep things can then pull it from there.,
